# Apps work with mobile data, but not WiFi?

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, mobile-data

I have an android phone, where spotify and instagram refuse to work, and behaves as if there is no internet connection when the phone is connected to my home WiFi.

If I switch to mobile data, these apps work perfectly. I don't know what's causing the issue since my WiFi connection on the phone works fine otherwise.

After a factory reset to the phone, I get the same results.

I can't afford to use mobile data all the time, anything I could do to disguise my WiFi? As I assume this is a trust issue of some sort...

This only happens on this one phone, on my other devices I have no problems with my WiFi connection and these apps.

Comment: Well, it seems there is something wrong with your phone, something related to the hardware that receives/sends WiFi... That would be my guess...

Comment: I don't believe so, as this only happens with 2 apps, WiFi works fine otherwise. The 2 apps also worked perfectly by using mobile data via WiFi connection by connecting to another phone with mobile hotspot enabled.

Comment: Have you tried some different (better/faster) WiFi networks? It seems those apps need constant data, and the network isn't able to fulfill the needs.

Comment: No, but my WiFi is much faster than my data...